# Error in sending email in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, email

how to send mail using javax.mail API in jsp .i am getting error like this so please tell me why i am getting problem or what will i have to do .

```
An error occurred at line: 6 in the jsp file: /mails.jsp
   Session cannot be resolved to a type
   3: String host = "pushkalit.in";
   4: Properties prop = new Properties();
   5: prop.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
   6: Session s = Session.getInstance(prop,null);
   7: MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(s);
   8: 
   9:  InternetAddress from = new InternetAddress("deepakniit1987@gmail.com");




        <%@ page import="java.util.*, javax.mail.*, javax.mail.internet.*, javax.mail.Session.*" %>
   <%
     String host = "pushkalit.in";
      Properties prop = new Properties();
      prop.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
      Session s = Session.getInstance(prop,null);
       MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(s);

      InternetAddress from = new InternetAddress("deepakniit1987@gmail.com");
          message.setFrom(from);
        InternetAddress to = new InternetAddress("deepakniit1987@gmail.com");
       message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, to);

         message.setSubject("Test from JavaMail.");
       message.setText("Hello from JavaMail!");
          Transport.send(message);
      %>
    <html>
     <p align="center">A Message has been sent.<br>Check your inbox.</p>
      <p align="center"><a href="mailjavax.jsp">Click here to send another!</a></p>
      </html>
```

Comment: your smtp server doesn't need authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change your import statement to

> "javax.mail.Session" instead of "javax.mail.Session.*"